# Парне тире, складносур. реч

Tags: граматика

Чи грам. правильно виділяти суряду частину за доп. подвійного тире? Приклад: Якщо я купую у інтернет магазині техніку - оплачую на банк. рах. - чи ці кошти...

Comment: Чи Ви дивилися правила вживання тире [у «Правописі» (с. 230 і далі)](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/Pravopys.2019/ukr.pravopys-2019.pdf#page=230)? Чи підходить якийсь із пунктів під Ваш випадок?

Comment: Таких "рецидивистів" хочеться банити якось....